# How to pass data from component to the store Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to set some data from component to the store

```
    methods: { // my component
          ...mapMutations('lists', ['setContactListName']),//import function from  the store
          viewHandler (id, item) { // hadler
            this.$router.push(`/company/sample-contact/${id}`);
            this.setContactListName(item); // pass data to the function
          }
        }

    state() { // store
        return {
          contactListName: {}
        };
      },
    mutations:{
     setContactListName (state, payload) {// handler
          state.contactListName = payload;
        }
    }
```

After i clicked nothing happend, even there are no errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
methods: { // my component
  ...mapMutations(['setContactListName']), //import function from  the store
  viewHandler(id, item) { // hadler
    this.$router.push(`/company/sample-contact/${id}`);
    this.setContactListName(item); // pass data to the function
  }
}
```

or using **this.$store.commit**

```js
methods: { // my component
  viewHandler(id, item) { // hadler
    this.$router.push(`/company/sample-contact/${id}`);
    this.$store.commit('setContactListName', item);
  }
}
```